# Django order objects by specific related object field

Tags: python, django

In my project there is an Attraction model and an AttractionTag model related through a ForeignKey relationship. Every Attraction has the same set of AttractionTag, they differ only by the value field. 
Now, I want to order Attractions based on the value field of a specific AttractionTag. For example, there is an AttractionTag named 'modern' for every attraction. I want to order Attractions based on modern AttractionTag value field.

I've tried

```
attractions.order_by('-attractiontag__value')
```

but this command order Attractions on AttractionTag in general, not based on a particular AttractionTag.

Here are the models

```
class Attraction (models.Model) :
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=attractionImagePath, null=True, blank=False)
    imageTop = models.ImageField(upload_to=attractionTopImagePath, null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
class AttractionTag (models.Model):
    attraction=models.ForeignKey(Attraction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How can I solve?

Thank you

Comment: No this orders the `Attraction` *per* `AttractionTag`, since an `Attraction` can have zero, one or *more* `AttractionTag`s.

Comment: Since you're ordering based on the AttractionTag values, how about getting the AttractionTags _first_, order them, _then_ get all the matching Attractions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution.

```
tags = AttractionTag.objects.filter(attraction__city=city)  
tags = tags.filter(name='modern').order_by('-value')
attraction = [tag.attraction for tag in tags]
```

Should work